# Objective-C, Buzztouch coding alerts - Data argument not used by format string and Semantic issue. Can someone explain what is going on?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, buzztouch

I'm currently running Mountain Lion OS X 10.8 with Xcode 4.4 installed.  I'm running the iOS 5.1 simulator.  I'm using Buzztouch as a learning tool while I'm studying Objective-C and Xcode.  I get the following alerts when I compile, but the build succeeds.  However, I would like to know exactly what is going on and how I can remedy the situation.  Thank you for any assistance you can provide.  Here's the code and the alerts I'm getting:

BT_fileManager.m

1. Data argument not used by format string
   [BT_debugger showIt:self:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"readTextFileFromBundleWithEncoding ERROR using encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding, trying NSISOLatin1StringEncoding", @""]];
2. Data argument not used by format string
   [BT_debugger showIt:self:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"readTextFileFromCacheWithEncoding ERROR using encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding, trying NSISOLatin1StringEncoding", @""]];

BT_camera_email.m

1. Semantic Issue
   Sending 'BT_camera_email *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        NSLog(@"is camera ok");
        UIActionSheet *photoSourceSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image Source"
                                                                      delegate:self

Again, thanks.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what Buzztouch might be, however....  :-)

The first warning is fairly simple.  In a format string there are placeholders beginning with a '%' sign to indicate where data values should be substituted.  For example, to substitute a string, one would use '%@'.  In the examples you show, there are no placeholders but there **are** data values -- empty strings.  The compiler is warning that something you indicate you want to have put into the new string created by `stringWithFormat:` won't be.

To be sure about the second one, I'd want to see the .h file that declares `BT_camera_email` but my best guess is that it doesn't adopt the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol.  The description of `initWithTitle:...` says the second parameter should be `id<UIActionSheetDelegate>` and that's probably what is being complained about.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is very helpful.  Buzztouch is a canned iOS/Android framework.  Basically, it's something that's aiming to be like wordpress for apps.  Unlike a lot of other template style app makers, it packages and allows you to download the source code for either iOS or Android.  It's nice for me because I'm learning Objective-C and it allows me to see how things work and tinker with the code.  Again, thanks for the clear explanation.